# how to map a row of a csv file to specific rows in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a strange looking csv file. It has sub sections and each sub section has csv formatted data.

Data e.g:

```
Device Name: Test-0001

Sub section 1
header 1, header 2, header 3,header 4,.......header n
field 1, field 2, field 3, field 4, .......field n

Sub section 2
header 1, header 2, header 3,header 4,.......header n
field 1, field 2, field 3, field 4, .......field n

.....

Sub section n

header 1, header 2, header 3,header 4,.......header n
field 1, field 2, field 3, field 4, .......field n

Device Name: Test2-0002
and same format afterwards....
```

I am looking to map each "Device Name: " to all the sub sections until next "Device Name :" comes

How can I do it?

Comment: Is it literally `'Sub section 2'`? Are all the headers the same?

Comment: It has a different name like 'System Information' and other sub section can be e.g 'Chassis Information'

Comment: What is the exact format? Is it always one blank line between 'System Information' and the column headers?

Comment: no, between sub section there is a blank line. between system information and column header there is no space but a NULL character

Comment: @ burhan, please check your google plus. i emailed you there

Comment: @ burhan, not all the headers are same. they are different, depending on which sub section it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to define a dictionary taking your devices as keys and a list of lines as values.
Assuming that `lines` is a list of the lines of your file:

```
with open(your_file_name, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

devices = {}
key = None
for line in lines:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    if line.startswith("Device Name"):
        key = get_key(line)
        devices[key] = []
    else:
        devices[key].append(line)
```

where `get_key` is a function you would define, that would transform a line like `Device Name: Test2-0002` into something you want.

For example, if you want your key like `Device Name: Test2-0002`, you could define `get_key` as `get_key = lambda line: line`: it's a function that when given a `line` will return exactly the same `line` without any processing.

If you want your key to be like `Test2-0002`, you could write your `get_key` function to remove the `Device Name:` string, or take the part of the string after the `':'`...

It's rather basic a solution but should work if you don't mind storing the lines of your file at once. If this is a problem, just use a `file.readline()` instead of the `lines` list.

A slightly more advanced solution could be based on the `mmap` module: find the positions of your `Device Name` lines and store them. You can then read section by section.

Comment: @ pierre GM, thx for the input but i am a noob. Can you tell me how to read in the csv and use your method ?

Comment: @Mustahsan Edited to show you how to read a file and store its lines in one go. You could also do `with open(...) as f: for line in f`

Comment: @ pierre GM, i tried but it gives syntax error. i am using python 2.7.3

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 13, in <module>
    devices[key].append(line)
KeyError: None

Comment: Your error tells you that `key=None`. How do you define `key`? What do you have for the `get_key` function I was suggesting? Make sure it returns something...

Comment: where get_key is a function you would define, that would transform a line like Device Name: Test2-0002 into something you want (you could have a simple get_key = lambda x: x)

could be please eloborate this function? I want to map Device Name: Test2-0001 with the csv formatted data in the file, so that I know this data belongs to a specific Device.

Comment: I edited the post to show you how you could write such a `get_key` function. Once again, if you don't want to be fancy, just use the lambda function I gave you, try it and see what it does.